# Two figures in one plot

Tags: python, colors

I'm trying to plot two figures from colour.plotting in one plot.
I know there's a show-Parameter so I tried to show only second figure but it won't work:

```
import colour

colour.plotting.plot_planckian_locus_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(["A", "B", "C"],show=False);
colour.plotting.plot_RGB_colourspaces_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(["ITU-R BT.709", "ITU-R BT.2020"],show=True)
```